# How can I display an integer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a function that will show lives up in the corner and it feels like I've looked everywhere, but everything seems to be either outdated or just straight up not work. for example, I found this:

```cs
Terminal.Writeline($"You have this many lives left: {tries}");
```

But every time I try it gives me an error saying:

> error CS1644: Feature `interpolated strings' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

Comment: Hello, @Oliver, and welcome to Stack Overflow. The string interpolation feature in C# is denoted by the `$"…{…}…"` syntax, where the contents of `{…}` are executed as C# statements. That's [a feature that was introduced in C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). So you either need to upgrade your application to use _at least_ C# 6, or you need to not use string interpolation. E.g., you might instead say, `Terminal.Writeline("You have this many lives left: " + tries);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, string interpolation is not supported by C# 4.0. In fact, the [string interpolation feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) wasn't introduced until C# 6.0.

To back up a bit, string interpolation is a syntax feature which allows the `$"…{…}…"` syntax:

```cs
Terminal.Writeline($"You have this many lives left {tries}");
```

> Note the use of the preceding dollar sign (`$`) and the braces (`{…}`) within the text. In this syntax, the content within the braces (`{…}`) are evaluated as C# statements. So, the value of the variable `tries` is evaluated, and inserted into the string.

To use this functionality, you need to update your project to use *at least* C# 6.0. Be aware that C# is currently up to 8.0, which enables a *lot* of useful syntactical shortcuts that weren't yet available in 4.0.

Alternatively, you can employ a different form of inserting a variable into a string, such as `string.Format()`:

```cs
Terminal.Writeline(String.Format("You have this many lives left {0}", tries));
```

Or even basic string concatenation:

```cs
Terminal.Writeline("You have this many lives left: " + tries);
```

The above two approaches are functionally equivalent to the string interpolation used in your code sample, but will work with any version of C# going back to 1.0. (Though the [`Format()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-1.1) wasn't introduced until .NET Framework 1.1.)